# How to implement themed icons by Material You in my Android App?

Tags: android-12, material-you

I can't find anything about that online, no documentation, nothing. Maybe one of you know how to do it or have got some advice for me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update on 02/18/2022:** Android 13 has official support for themed icons. Just follow their steps here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features#themed-app-icons

To follow their example:

1. Create a monochrome version of your app icon
2. Add this to your `ic_launcher.xml` file, under the `<adaptive-icon />` tagset:

   ```xml
   <adaptive-icon>
       <background android:drawable="..." />
       <foreground android:drawable="..." />
       <monochrome android:drawable="@drawable/myicon" />
   </adaptive-icon>
   ```
3. Add your icon to your manifest:

   ```xml
   <application
       …
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       …>
   </application>
   ```

**Note:** If `android:roundIcon` and `android:icon` are both in your manifest, you must either remove the reference to `android:roundIcon` or supply the monochrome icon in the drawable defined by the `android:roundIcon` attribute.

All of that was pulled directly from the Google developer's example.

---

There seems to be competing answers on this, but this issue on the Material Components GitHub repository seems to offer the most insight: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2357

Particularly, using an adaptive icon, like this:

```xml
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <background android:drawable="@color/launcher_icon_background"/>

    <foreground>
        <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
            <vector
                android:width="108dp"
                android:height="108dp"
                android:viewportWidth="108"
                android:viewportHeight="108">
                <path
                    android:fillColor="@color/launcher_icon"
                    android:pathData="m54,74.5l23.3,-29c-0.9,-0.7 -9.9,-8 -23.3,-8c-13.4,0 -22.4,7.3 -23.3,8l23.3,29l0,0c0,0 0,0 0,0zm7.7,-27.3c1.4,1.7 2.3,3.9 2.3,6.3l0,2l-20,0l0,-2c0,-2.4 0.9,-4.6 2.3,-6.3l-2.3,-2.3l1.4,-1.4l2.3,2.3c1.7,-1.4 3.9,-2.3 6.3,-2.3c2.4,0 4.6,0.9 6.3,2.3l2.3,-2.3l1.4,1.4l-2.3,2.3zm-9.7,4.3c0,1.1 -0.9,2 -2,2c-1.1,0 -2,-0.9 -2,-2c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2zm8,0c0,1.1 -0.9,2 -2,2c-1.1,0 -2,-0.9 -2,-2c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2z" />
                </vector>
        </aapt:attr>
    </foreground>
</adaptive-icon>
```

... with colors defined in `colors.xml` that refer to system-defined colors that derive from the Material 3 color pallet:

```xml
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_icon_background">@android:color/system_accent1_100</color>
    <color name="launcher_icon">@android:color/system_neutral1_800</color>
</resources>
```

Note that these colors derive from the system-defined pallet, as described in Material Design 3: https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/color-theming

You will likely have to create separate resource files that target API 31+ specifically. I have not tested out these recommendations.

Comment: It works but how do I achieve that the design only applies if themed icons is activated in the android device settings?

Comment: nvm i saw that this is a pixel launcher feature. thx for ur help

Comment: I have no idea on that second question, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Note that adaptive icon were introduced in Android 8.0 (API level 26).

Comment: @Tom I also see the colours always applied even if the themed icons are turned off, how did you solve this?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Basically, you can't with Android 12. Checkout this feature for Android 13, though: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features#themed-app-icons