# How to inherit the color of the Material You icon? Without Jetpack compose

Tags: android-layout, material-design, material-components-android, material-you

I want to change the color of my icon according to material You, like a google app, but the color does not change in any way. All unsuccessfully

[it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMjEC.jpg)

[or it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYZW6.jpg)

according to the applied theme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement themed icons by Material You in my Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800362/how-to-implement-themed-icons-by-material-you-in-my-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

This process does not require Jetpack Compose at all. Android 13 has official support for themed icons. Just follow their steps here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features#themed-app-icons

To follow their example:

1. Create a monochrome version of your app icon
2. Add this to your `ic_launcher.xml` file, under the `<adaptive-icon />` tagset:

   ```xml
   <adaptive-icon>
       <background android:drawable="..." />
       <foreground android:drawable="..." />
       <monochrome android:drawable="@drawable/myicon" />
   </adaptive-icon>
   ```
3. Add your icon to your manifest:

   ```xml
   <application
       …
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       …>
   </application>
   ```

**Note:** If `android:roundIcon` and `android:icon` are both in your manifest, you must either remove the reference to `android:roundIcon` or supply the monochrome icon in the drawable defined by the `android:roundIcon` attribute.

All of that was pulled directly from the Google developer's example.

Comment: Thank you! Other resources on this I found didn't mention rounded icon needed to be changed as well, and I couldn't figure out what was wrong. It's working now!